# Select all text in UISearchBar on beginEditing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, uisearchbar

I’m trying to emulate the behaviour of the address bar in iOS Safari – that is, if there’s text in the address bar when it’s tapped, it is selected. Much in the same way most desktop browsers work, too. I don’t want to CLEAR it on selection, merely select what’s inside, so that if the user then begins typing, it’ll clear, but the user also has the ability to edit the existing string if they want to.

I’ve tried the following, it finds the `UISearchBarTextField` inside the subviews under both iOS7 and iOS6, but calling `selectAll` on it doesn’t seem to have any effect. I’ve tried changing its `text` property, that works fine, it’s just `selectAll` that isn’t happy.

I’ve also tried changing the argument to `selectAll:` to `self` and a couple other things, no change, just doesn’t wanna select the text in there!

Any thoughts? Here’s my code:

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    NSArray *subviews = [UIDevice isRunningiOS7OrAbove]
    ? [[searchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:0] subviews]
    : searchBar.subviews;

    for (UIView *subview in subviews) {
        if ([subview conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)]) {
            UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)subview;
            [textField selectAll:textField];
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I’ve also tried this, with no joy:

```
for (UIView *subview in subviews) {
    if ([subview conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)]) {
        UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)subview;
        [textField setSelectedTextRange:[textField textRangeFromPosition:[textField beginningOfDocument]
                                                              toPosition:[textField endOfDocument]]];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use: `[UITextField setSelectedTextRange:(UITextRange *)]`

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField*)textField {

 UITextPosition *start = [textField beginningOfDocument];

 UITextPosition *end   = [textField endOfDocument];

 UITextRange *range = [textField textRangeFromPosition:start toPosition:end];

 [textField setSelectedTextRange:range];

 }
```

Now you can implement using `UISearchBar`...

Comment: Nope, no effect either I’m afraid. Doesn’t select anything. Looks like it’s doing SOMETHING, though: if I printout `textField.selectedTextRange` before and after the call, I get:
`Before: <_UITextKitTextRange: 0x161da8d0> (8, 0)F`
`After: <_UITextKitTextRange: 0xd648840> (0, 8)F` for an eight-character string.

Comment: Yup. It's strange, it's obviously having some effect or other, it's just not actually making the selection in the UI. If I type, it's appended to the end, for instance, rather than replacing the selection.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same problem. The thing that helped me was delaying the `selectAll` by a short period of time.

I made this extension for `UISearchBar`

```
extension UISearchBar {
    func selectAllText() {
        guard let searchTF = self.valueForKey("searchField") as? UITextField else {
            return
        }

        if searchTF.respondsToSelector(#selector(NSObject.selectAll(_:))) {
            searchTF.selectAll(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

then I simply call this method on my searchbar with a short delay.

Swift 2

```
let dispatchTime: dispatch_time_t = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(0.05 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) 
dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), { [weak self] in
    self?.nameSearchBar.selectAllText()
})
```

Swift 3 Xcode 8 beta 4

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.05) { [weak self] in
    self?.nameSearchBar.selectAllText()
}
```

**WARNING:**
This approach is far from clear solution, but it works fine. The short delay shouldn't cause any trouble since it's just a selecting action on a textfield. Though accessing the `searchField` property of your `UISearchBar` can lead to app rejection!

Answer (score 0):

For me passing UITextField parameter didnt work. I am passing to selectAll method nil param so your line should look like:

```
    [textField selectAll:nil];
```

Comment: Nope, using `nil` makes no difference, I’m afraid. The `[textField selectAll:nil]` line is called, but the text doesn’t select in the field.