# Select all text in a UITextField

Tags: swift, uitextfield

How do you programatically select all the text in a Swift text field?

like Safari

[image]

I try to like this:

```
textField.becomeFirstResponder()

textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRange(from: textField.beginningOfDocument, to: textField.endOfDocument)
```

or this:

```
textField.selectAll(self)
```

but it is not the effect I want.

Comment: What do you want it to look like when you start adding more text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only aim to select all the text in the UITextField,
use this:

```
textField.selectAll(nil)
```

Comment: can you explain the "effect" you want aside from selecting all the text from the field?

Comment: I uploaded the picture, like safari address bar selects the effect

Comment: Oh, I see. hmm.
If you want it to have an effect like that, you have to use the UISearchBar.
Though I'm not that confident regarding the approach in selecting text from UISearchBar programmatically.

Comment: I looked for a similar question, can you try if one of the answers here work for UISearchBars?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21281439/select-all-text-in-uisearchbar-on-beginediting

Comment: After choosing the text, there are two sliders that can be dragged, and I want to remove the slider. how can I to do it

Comment: ohh, the selection indicators. hmm. let me try that. be right back after finding a solution, hopefully

Comment: i still can't find an answer. I will also try to ask here with the specifics you told me and link you to it

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts